# R, how do i know the number of row that this matrix has equal to the first value of this other matrix?

Tags: r

im making a code that need to know the number of rows on base[,2] that have the same value of sol[1,1], i was hoping that you can helpme

```
> base
    id folio  dato
1 z123  3345 dato1
2 z124  3345 dato1
3 z125  3345 dato1
4 z126  2124 dato3
5 z127  2123 dato2
6 z128  2124 dato4
7 z180  2124 dato5
8 z181  2124 dato6
```

and

```
> sol
  folio
1  3345
2  2124
3  2123
```

thank u in advance

Comment: Try `sum(base[,2] == sol$folio[1])`

Comment: srry what is dolio?

Comment: sorry, it is a typo, `folio`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do a logical comparison and get the `sum` of TRUE values

```
sum(base[,2] == sol$folio[1])
```

Comment: hey mand dont know if i should post this here, but now if i have another one (a zero matrix) created by 

    z <- matrix(0,length(base[1,]),sum(base[,2]==sol[1,1]))

how do i fill the z matrix whit the values that(for example) has base[,2] == sol[1,1] ??

tank u in advance

Comment: @mimus Do you need `z[,2] <- base[which(base[,2] == sol[1,1]), 2]`

Comment: thanks for the help, but the thing is i need to fill all z matrix whit the values of base that has the folio equal to the first entry of sol, in this example the first 3 rows of base, srry if im not explaining myself, im trying w/ for cycle but i did not solve it yet

Comment: @mimus Can you update your post with the xpected output as it is not clear to me where the values should be filled

Comment: i got it!! z <- base[which(base[,2]==sol[1,1]),] tank u for ur help!